# how to autorecalkulate remove tr button

Tags: jquery

If click button class ".myaddrremove" remove my table row.

How can I achieve after clicking on remove tr ".myaddremove" to recalculate the result in the end container for class ".cenaa , .fzlavaa,.ssumadph,.nauhradu" ??

when I click delete a row does not work recalculate if I add a new row recalculate works. How can I achieve a recalculation when I remove tr?

```
 $(document).on('click', '.myaddremove', function(){
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });

// CALKULATE TR
calkulatemy();

function calkulatemy() {

$(document).change(function () {
    $('.mnozstvo, .cenaj , .zlava , .cenakpl , .dphpercentaa, .sumadpha ,.polozkaspolua').change(function () {
        let parents = $(this).closest( 'tr')
        parents.find('.cenakpl').val(parseFloat(parents.find('.mnozstvo').val()) * parseFloat(parents.find('.cenaj').val()))
        parents.find('.cenakpl').val(parseFloat(parents.find('.cenakpl').val()) - parseFloat(parents.find('.zlava').val()))
        parents.find('.sumadpha').val(parseFloat(parents.find('.cenakpl').val()) / 100 * parseFloat(parents.find('.dphpercentaa').val()))
        parents.find('.polozkaspolua').val(parseFloat(parents.find('.cenakpl').val()) + parseFloat(parents.find('.sumadpha').val()))

        let zlava = 0;
        let cena = 0;
        let dph = 0;

        $('.zlava').each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('zlava')) {
                    zlava += parseFloat(this.value);
                }
            }
        });
        $('.fzlavaa').val(zlava.toFixed(2));


        $('.cenakpl').each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('cenakpl')) {
                    cena += parseFloat(this.value);
                }
            }
        });
        $('.cenaa').val(cena.toFixed(2));


        $('.sumadpha').each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('sumadpha')) {
                    dph += parseFloat(this.value);
                }
            }
        });
        $('.ssumadph').val(dph.toFixed(2));


            $('.cenaa , .fzlavaa , .ssumadph , .nauhradu').each(function () {
                let parents = $(this).closest('tr')
                parents.find('.nauhradu').val(parseFloat(parents.find('.cenaa').val()) + parseFloat(parents.find('.ssumadph').val()))
            });


    });

});

}
```

Comment: You can call `calkulatemy();` function inside `$(document).on('click', '.myaddremove'..` but why you are having `.change` inside function ?

Comment: if calkulatemy() call function inside $(document).on('click','.myaddremove') no efect  no change will be made